# Fatal exception (java.lang.IllegalStateException)

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to search for an answer but the only thing i understood is there's something wrong at line 22 of my code, but i don't get why. I'm sure it's something stupid, but i started yesterday to code android, so forgive me please!

My code is:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Benvenuto extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_benvenuto);
       }



public void entra(View view) {
    Intent entra1 = new Intent(this, domande1.class);
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.condizioni:
            if (checked)
                startActivity(entra1);
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Devi approvare termini e condizioni prima di procedere!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }

}
}
```

So, basically, user has to agree to terms and conditions. If he agrees, good, he jumps to the next activity. If not, a toast appears!

But the app crashes when i press the button (before adding the checkbox, it worked fine).

The error i get is

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.suspicio.turboscuse, PID: 547
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21209)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21209) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox
                  at com.suspicio.turboscuse.Benvenuto.entra(Benvenuto.java:22)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21209) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: This line: `((CheckBox) view)`. You're casting an object that's not a `CheckBox`

Comment: Is line 22 the one where you create the variable checked? Are you sure that view is of type CheckBox? I can't reproduce the crash as long as you don't show us the layout xml file.

Comment: please add your xml file

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `view` variable is not a `CheckBox` it seems to be a `AppCompatButton`.

You could change your check to something like this:

```
if(view instanceof CheckBox){
   // The checkbox was pressed
   if(((CheckBox) view).isChecked()){
      // The checkbox is checked
      startActivity(entra1);
   }else{
     // The checkbox is not checked
     Toast.makeText(this, "Devi approvare termini e condizioni prima di procedere!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}else{
    // The button was pressed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void itemClicked(View v) {
  CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v;
  if(checkBox.isChecked())
     startActivity(entra1);
  else
     Toast.makeText(this, "Devi approvare termini e condizioni prima di procedere!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

In the xml:

```
<CheckBox
   android:id="@+id/check_box"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:onClick="itemClicked" />
```